# Find all rows with matching columns with two conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want to find which orders have *two* rows in the line_items table and also where *one of those rows* has the sku of BALL.  Basically trying to find all the customers who ordered only a ball, regardless of the qty of the BALL row.  There needs to be two rows per order at least, because one of the rows will always be for the SHIPPING sku.

In the below data, john and sam would be the only valid orders returned because the only skus their orders have in the line_items table are BALL and SHIPPING (regardless of BALL qty).  I'd like the tables joined so that the returned data would have the order_id, customer, date_placed, and qty.

```
TABLE orders
id   customer   date_placed
===========================
0    john       1/1/2000
1    bill       2/1/2000
2    sam        2/5/2000


TABLE line_items
id   order_id   qty   sku
=========================
0    0          1     BALL
1    0          1     SHIPPING

2    1          1     BALL
3    1          1     ROPE
4    1          1     SHIPPING

5    2          3     BALL
6    2          1     SHIPPING
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to write it like this:

```
SELECT o.id, customer, date_placed, li.qty
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN line_items li
  ON o.id=li.order_id AND li.sku='BALL'
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT order_id 
  FROM line_items tli 
  WHERE o.id=tli.order_id 
  GROUP BY order_id 
  HAVING count(*)=2)
```

Comment: thank you, i have gotten that far.  but the part i can't overcome is limiting it only to orders that have only skus BALL and SHIPPING.  meaning john and sam are ok, but bill should not be returned (which your example does return) because his order has skus BALL, ROPE, and SHIPPING.

Comment: okay. I misunderstood. I have updated the answer to only include orders that have 2 line items.